# I want to find the least out of three, what is the issue with the code?

Tags: python

this is the code i tried to make but it won't do the calculations in the way i intended, i wanted to return the minimum value out of e1,e2 and e3

```
def hra_exemption_calc():
    #Variables
    city1 = 'Delhi'
    city2 = 'Kolkata'
    city3 = 'Chennai'
    city4 = 'Mumbai'
    e1 = 0  
    e2 = 0  
    e3 = 0  
    exemption = 0
    #Criterias
    place = str(input('Enter your place of employment: '))
    basic = int(input('Enter your basic salary: '))
    rent = int(input('Enter your rent for an year: '))
    #Calculation
    if rent > 0.1 * basic:
        return e1 == 0.1 * basic
    
    if place := [city1,city2,city3,city4]:
        return e2 == 0.5 * basic 
    else:
        return e2 == 0.4 * basic
    e3 = rent
    
    #Finding the least exemption
    exemption = min(e1,e2,e3)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to assign a value to a variable (such as e1, e2, and e3), you are supposed to use a single equal sign (`=`).
You should just calculate your three variables, then take the minimum with the `min` function and return it.

```py
if rent > 0.1 * basic:
    e1 = 0.1 * basic
   
if place := [city1,city2,city3,city4]:
    e2 = 0.5 * basic 
else:
    e2 = 0.4 * basic

e3 = rent
    
#Finding the least exemption
exemption = min([e1,e2,e3])
return exemption
```

Also I'm not sure what are you doing with the `:=` operator in your if statement, this would just create a new variable called `place`, and the statement would be always `True`.